# replicating and merging.the data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have no clue on how to do this in Power BI/DAX and asking for help.

I have 2 folders (current, previous) that I want to merge. G1 Previous needs to be appended to each G1 Current and then merged.  G2 previous needs to be merged with each G2 current and merged together. Finally, G1 and G2 are merged together forming a single dataset for Power BI.

All the files have the same data structure.

If i can get help to figure out how to handle G1 files, I can get G2 and the final merger.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Additional Information
Here’s an example of the append steps

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "append" and "merge"?  Generally, start with the Folder connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/folder

Comment: Sorry, I used merged and append interchangeably.   Everything is appended together.   For example 'G1 Previous 230901.txt' is appended to 'G1 Current 1001 0045.txt' then 'G1 Previous 230901.txt' appended to 'G1 Current 1002 1600.txt'.  This is done for each current file.  Once all the current and previous files been appended, all of these lists are appended together to create a one big list that is used by power BI.
All the lists have the same column headers.

I'm aware of the folder connector but how do you append previous file to each current?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the folder connector to create a query for each folder, and then [append the two queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/append-queries).

Comment: David,  the results will be wrong.  I added steps above to show how the append is supposed to work.   I don't want to manually append 16-20 different files and then append all of these together.    There should be  way to do this using DAX.